# Python Ipywidgets: Passing Button (value/description) on click to a textarea widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipywidgets

I'm currently trying out ipywidgets in Jupyter. I wanted to pass the value or description that the button has to the textArea and append whichever button value it indicates.

So far this is the code that I have:

```
#testing adding button and textbox
from ipywidgets import widgets as wd
from ipywidgets import Layout, Box
from IPython.display import display

btnLayout = Layout(flex='1 1 auto', width='auto')

btns= [
    wd.Button(description="Add Route"),
    wd.Button(description="234"),
    wd.Button(description="411")
]

box_layout = Layout(display='flex',
                    flex_flow='row',
                    align_items='stretch')

box = Box(children=btns, layout=box_layout)

display(box)
box.children[1].layout.visibility = 'hidden'
box.children[2].layout.visibility = 'hidden'

txtArea = wd.Textarea()
display(txtArea)

def show(b):
    box.children[1].layout.visibility = 'visible'
    box.children[2].layout.visibility = 'visible'

#function intended to append button value/description to textArea
def add_text(b):
    txtArea.value = "test, " + txtArea.value

box.children[0].on_click(show)
box.children[1].on_click(add_text)
box.children[2].on_click(add_text)
```

I read about links and observe... but I don't think it will do what I intend to have in my code. Any ideas how to work around this if there is no direct way, unlike the intsliders etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify the `Button` class in `ipywidgets` does not have a `value` attribute but you can add one by subclassing it ([see this gist for an example of that](https://gist.github.com/draperjames/aa5ff93c24373434421f00693724a521)).

If I understood the question correctly I think that this will work for you;

```py
#testing adding button and textbox
from ipywidgets import widgets as wd
from ipywidgets import Layout, Box
from IPython.display import display

btnLayout = Layout(flex='1 1 auto', width='auto')

btns= [
    wd.Button(description="Add Route"),
    wd.Button(description="234"),
    wd.Button(description="411")
]

box_layout = Layout(display='flex',
                    flex_flow='row',
                    align_items='stretch')

box = Box(children=btns, layout=box_layout)

display(box)
box.children[1].layout.visibility = 'hidden'
box.children[2].layout.visibility = 'hidden'

txtArea = wd.Textarea()
display(txtArea)

def show(b):
    box.children[1].layout.visibility = 'visible'
    box.children[2].layout.visibility = 'visible'

#function intended to append button value/description to textArea
def add_text(b):
    txtArea.value = b.description + txtArea.value

box.children[0].on_click(show)
box.children[1].on_click(add_text)
box.children[2].on_click(add_text)
```

Please comment below if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Yes it worked! just had to switch between which comes first in the append. Also thanks for the subclassing tip. I thought the b in the function is just boolean. May I know what's the difference between 'box.children[1].on_click(add_text, ) # <--- THIS
box.children[2].on_click(add_text)' # <--- and THIS